# Functions and Derivatives

Tags: functions, derivatives

Generaly curious:

Let there be a set of functions:

Will the sum of the derivatives of the functions be equal to the derivative of the sums?

Comment: Yes, for finite sets of differentiable functions. Not necesarily for even countable sets.

Comment: Finite sum?  sure.  Infinite?  Not necessarily.

Comment: The finite case is a direct application of the analogous property of limits (which makes sense since the definition of the derivative is a limit!).

Comment: Adding to the other answers, the statement of course fails generally for any finite set of _arbitrary_ functions. Take the Dirichlet function and its converse. Let $f_1(x)$ be $1$ for $x$ rational and $0$ for $x$ irrational, and let $f_2(x)$ be $0$ for $x$ rational and $1$ for $x$ irrational. The derivative of their sum is zero everywhere, but the sum of their derivatives does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

For finite sums, there is no problem.

For infinite sum the answer is no. One may consider, for example,
$$
f(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(2^nx)}{n^2}, \quad x \in [0,\pi/2]
$$ which converges normally over $[0,\pi/2]$:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left|\frac{\sin(2^nx)}{n^2}\right|\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}<\infty.
$$
But, for $x \in [0,\pi/2]$,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty f'_n(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^n\cos(2^nx)}{n^2}
$$ **does not exist**, since for $x \in [0,\pi/2]$,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2^n\cos(2^nx)}{n^2}\neq 0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

It depends! If you mean sum of FINITE functions, it is true!

For infinite, you have to check the convergence of the sum of the $f_n'$ to derivate term by term!